# how to get updated props after redux action called using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux

this is my container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import Login from './Login';
import { loginAction } from './LoginAction';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log('mapStateToProps', state)
  return {
    payload: state.Auth
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  console.log('mapDispatchToProps')
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      loginAction
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

this is my function in my component

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    
    const form = event.currentTarget
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
      return false
    }
    setValidated(true)

    props.loginAction(username, password).then(() =>{
      console.log('props loginAction', props) // this props not updated immediately after loginAction called
      if (props.payload.error){
        return false
      }
    })

    // navigate('/dashboard')
  }

  useEffect(()=>{console.log('payload effect', props.payload)},[props.payload])
```

this is my reducer

```
import * as types from './LoginActionTypes';

var initialState = {
  loading: false,
  result: null,
  error: null,
  message: null,
};

function AuthReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ACTION_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true,
        error: null
      });
      break;
    case types.AUTHENTICATED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        status: true,
        result: action.payload
      });
      break;
    case types.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        status: false,
        error: action.error
      });
      break;
    case types.UNAUTHENTICATED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, initialState);
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default AuthReducer;
```

my question is how to get updated props after i call loginAction?
when im using react component is work fine, but im not sure if the problem is the functional component, any suggestion?

```
props.loginAction(username, password).then(() =>{
      console.log('props loginAction', props) // this props not updated immediately after loginAction called
      if (props.payload.error){
        return false
      }
    })
```

[this console that proof props mapStateToProps have new props, but the props still not updated, and useEffect is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17WfF.png)

Comment: You could read the outcome of `loginAction` from the state via `useSelector` and handle this in a `useEffect`. Or let the action return a value and use that. Alternatively, you can extend `loginAction` to redirect to a specific URL in the success case.

Comment: it work with added redirect in `loginAction`,  thanks timotgl

Answer (score 0):

To get actual props:

```js
//add this
const propsRef = React.useRef(props);
propsRef.current = props;

props.loginAction(username, password).then(() =>{
      console.log('props loginAction', propsRef.current) // <-- change this
      if (propsRef.current.payload.error){ // <--- and this
        return false
      }
    })
```